# How can I make hyperlinks open in a new tab using CSS or Multimarkdown?

Tags: html, css, perl, hyperlink, markdown

I am using [Text::MultiMarkdown](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aMultiMarkdown) to create HTML files from [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) documents.

I would like all links to open in a new tab.

Is there a way to configure this behavior using a CSS template, or directly in the MultiMarkdown document (without explicitly writing HTML around each link in the MultiMarkdown document)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely not in CSS - that is only concerned with the way the elements appear, not how they behave.

It should be possible to add `<base target="_blank">` to the head of the HTML document (using XSLT), but that's on par with adding it to each link.

Comment: @coding crow: "you can do [obscure CSS hack], *but it won't work anywhere* (within the margin of statistical error)"? Sounds just like "you can't", i.e. my statement is correct and needs no updates.

Answer (score 3):

In HTML and/or JavaScript you can only initialize the opening of a new window. The user is in some UAs able to force the opening of a new window as a new tab instead. But you can not control this behaviour.

Comment: Bingo! The user is in control of whether the document opens as a tab or a separate window. I think that some browsers even allow replacing the existing window with the new one in spite of the `<base target="_blank">` setting.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could do this with CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-hyperlinks/ - however no common browser ever implemented this. The reason might be that it is a common believe that the choice of when a new window or tab is opened should be left to the user alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in CSS but you can use the source.

You could subclass `Text::MultiMarkdown` and provide your own implementation of `_GenerateAnchor`, something similar to this might work:

```
sub _GenerateAnchor {
    my ($self, $whole_match, $link_text, $link_id, $url, $title, $attributes) = @_;
    if($url
    && index($url, '#') != 0) {
        $attributes = $attributes ? $attributes . ' target="_blank"' : 'target="_blank"';
    }
    return $self->SUPER::_GenerateAnchor($whole_match, $link_text, $link_id, $url, $title, $attributes);
}
```

This is a bit kludgey as `_GenerateAnchor` isn't part of the public interface. You'd also need to use the OO interface rather than just the `markdown` function.

You could also contact the `Text::MultiMarkdown` author and see if he'll add a flag for this sort of thing. Maybe you could provide a patch to get things started.

You can also use `HTML::Parser` and friends to parse the HTML that comes out of `Text::MultiMarkdown` and add the `target` attributes yourself.